# How to access spring boot application direct from keycloak?

Tags: spring-mvc, keycloak

The normal scenario that I can access my application URL and then my request redirected to the login page of keycloak. what I need is accessing keycloak login page direct and then after login, the redirection happened to my application.

Comment: Just curious why would you want to do that? I mean that is not how keycloak is meant be used

Comment: it's for security purpose and business needs, as we do not need the application to be available in the public network just the keycloak will be available.